# Issues when grabbing words of a specific length from a txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The main confusion I am having with my code is that I am aiming to find all the words in the dictionary.txt of a particular length containing just a single vowel (defined as a, e, i, o and u) that does not have a particular letter in it. However, it does not work correctly. For example, if I am looking for all the words of length 9 containing just a single vowel that does not have letter ‘t’ in it, the
program below tells me “There are no words that fit this criteria”. But there should be two
words in the file satisfying the above criteria: “lynchings”, and “lynchpins”.

My dictionary is located at https://filebin.net/96k7kso4i6nxcd2n/dictionary.txt?t=x9ujn62v

```
def onevowel(file):
length = int(input("Please enter the word length you are looking for: "))
letter = input("Please enter the letter you'd like to exclude: ")
wordnum = 0
for word in file:
    word = word.strip()
    if len(word) == length:
            count = 0
            for char in word:
                if (char=='a' and char=='e' and char=='i' and char=='o' and char=='u'):
                    count += 1
            if count == 1:
                flag = 1
                word_str = ""
                for char in word:
                    if char == letter:
                        flag = 0
                    else:
                        word_str += char
                if flag == 1:
                    print (word_str)
                    wordnum += 1
if wordnum == 0:
    print ("There are no words that fit this criteria.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_file = open("dictionary.txt","r")
    onevowel(my_file)
    my_file.close()
```

Comment: `char=='a' and char=='e' ...` Are you aware that this condition can never be true? The same variable cannot be equal to multiple values at the same time. You probably wanted to join them with `or`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `char=='a' and char=='e' and char=='i' and char=='o' and char=='u'` (which is never true) with `char in "aeoui"`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize that my use of "and" was requiring all of them together. Need to brush up on logic. I will mark this as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you want only a single vowel, use the `or` condition rather than `and` in this line:

```
if (char=='a' and char=='e' and char=='i' and char=='o' and char=='u'):
```